# OnLoaded event calling again in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit, winui

I'm working with UWP with `WinUI 2.5 prerelease` and have noticed a strange behavior which doesn't happen in `WPF`.
So i'm using a `TabView` control and loading a `Page` in it. Every time a new tab is created, a new page is loaded in it (nothing fancy).

Now, I have some `OnLoaded` events on my pages. so when a new tab is created and page is loaded, the `OnLoad` event is called (as it should) but now when i switch back to other tab and switch again to current page the `OnLoaded` event is called again. WHY ?

**MainPage with TabView**

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestUWPApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestUWPApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <controls:TabView x:Name="MainTabView">
            <controls:TabView.TabItems>
                <controls:TabViewItem Header="Intelliventory"
                                      IsClosable="False" CanDrag="False">
                    <controls:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                        <controls:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Home" />
                    </controls:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                    <Frame SourcePageType="local:Page2" />
                </controls:TabViewItem>
                <controls:TabViewItem Header="Intelliventory"
                                      IsClosable="False" CanDrag="False">
                    <controls:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                        <controls:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Home" />
                    </controls:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                    <Frame SourcePageType="local:Page3" />
                </controls:TabViewItem>
            </controls:TabView.TabItems>
        </controls:TabView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Page3 that has an OnLoaded event**

```
namespace TestUWPApp
{

    public sealed partial class Page3 : Page
    {
        public Page3()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page3_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //This event is called every time tab is switched
        }
    }
}
```

Every time selected tab is changed to `Page3 tab` the `onLoaded` event is called. That should just be called once when first time the tab was switched and Page was loaded.

Comment: Hello, if you are using the pre-release WinUI package, you can ask your question on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/new/choose), and the developers are actively responding to relevant questions there.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT hi, I have asked there too but no response so far.(also i think same happens in non pre-release versions)

Comment: Have you tried the ChacheModes?public Page3()

 {

      this.InitializeComponent();

      this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;   
 }

Comment: @thezapper yeah i just tried this and it doesn't work either. Load events are called ! Someone told me on github that it happens cuz the controls are loaded in visual tree on tab navigations again and on this the load events are called.

Comment: and this feels not good to me for reason 1 that it doesn't happen in WPF and 2. the page was already loaded in tab so it shouldn't call load events again while switching tabs..

Answer (score 1):

The `Loaded` event gets raised every time the element gets added to the VisualTree, has rendered and is ready for interaction. If you select a TabViewItem, the TabViewItems page gets added to the visual tree again, gets rendered, and thus raises the Loaded event again. So this behaviors is by design.